# .NET IL Property setter

Tags: .net, intermediate-language

Consider this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    // Fields
    private string _bar;

    // Properties
    private string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return this._bar;
        }
        set
        {
            this._bar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I go and look in the IL code emitted by the compiler for the setter of the `Bar` property:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname instance void set_Bar(string 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldarg.1 
    L_0003: stfld string ConsoleApplication2.Program/Foo::_bar
    L_0008: ret 
}
```

Why does it do a `ldarg.0` ? WHAT is located in first (index 0) argument? Since the method/property setter only takes 1 argument...

The same goes for the getter:

```
.method private hidebysig specialname instance string get_Bar() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] string CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldfld string ConsoleApplication2.Program/Foo::_bar
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: br.s L_000a
    L_000a: ldloc.0 
    L_000b: ret 
}
```

Why the `.locals init` ? Why the ldarg.0 ? Why doesn't it do a `ldfld` of the backing field and just return that? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the setter:

Any instance member has an implicit "this" parameter - that's what's being loaded, basically. Try turning it into a static property and you'll see it go away.

For the getter, I'm not sure why there's the local variable... debugger support perhaps? Certainly compiling it in optimized mode (`/o+ /debug-` from the command line) gets rid of the local variable.

Comment: But why push it onto the stack? Seems like a waste of space to me.

Comment: @Snake: Don't forget that you're looking at the IL, not the final native code. Just because IL represents "getting a field from a particular instance" by pushing something onto the stack doesn't mean that's what really happens.

Comment: @Snake: Stack as in the evaluation stack, not stack memory vs heap memory.  ldfld will load a field but it needs an instance of the class to do so.  There is no implicit this, ergo the ldarg.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldfld.aspx  The rest of the inefficiency just looks like extra instructions left in by debug.